# Making a dots trace font

Tags: fontlab-studio, font-design, fontlab-fontographer

I made several styles of the same font family. How can I make one that translates it into a series of dots? (Resulting in a (round-)dot trace font)

Comment: You mean [something like this](http://www.ffonts.net/Trace-Font-for-Kids.font.download)?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Similar, yes, a style that uses many dots instead of a line

Comment: How have you made your font?

Comment: @Jenna shapes, not strokes if that is what you're referring to (Fontographer 5/ FontLab Studio 5.1.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to dork out on your solution, you could make a script in Processing to help automate the process a bit.

You can load the font as-is with the PFont function:
http://processing.org/reference/PFont.html

Generate ellipses in the shape path:
http://processing.org/reference/ellipse_.html

And then export the forms as PDFs:
http://processing.org/reference/libraries/pdf/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Is your typeface built up with strokes (as opposed to shapes)? Then, all you'll have to do is give those strokes a dotted line. In Illustrator, you'd use the stroke palette.

[image: dashed line in the stroke palette in Illustrator]

Then, `Object > Expand` the glyph.

Comment: @Bakabaka thank you for the answer. It is built with shapes, what else can we do?

Comment: You could try to trace the shapes with strokes. There's probably cleverer methods, but those are beyond my league.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a dot pattern as the fill on the shapes? Select the shape, and use the appearance palette to apply a dot pattern?